# Regex - Conditional Replace

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to do regex to validate a phone number by country.
I do a phone format by country, which contain :

- a validation regex (exemple : `^(\+33|0)([1-9][0-9]{8})$)`)
- a transformation to get international number (exemple : `+33$2`)
- a transformation to get national number (exemple : `0$2`)

About Italy, it is getting tricky.

Most phone numbers work like this :
"+39 123456789" => "**0** 123456789"

But for mobile, it is :
"+39 **3** 123456789" => "**3** 123456789"

Which means, to get the national phone number, i have to add a 0, except for mobile phone numbers.

So far, i only could achieve it by having 2 phones format, one for mobile, and another for other phones.
They are mutually exclusive.

mobile =>

- validation regex : `^(\+393|3)([0-9]{9})$`
- transformation to get international number : `+393$2`
- transformation to get national number : `3$2`

others =>

- validation regex : `^(\+39|0)([0-9]{9})$`
- transformation to get international number : `+39$2`
- transformation to get national number : `0$2`

Is there any way to do in one time ?

Phones samples :

- 0123456789
- +39123456789
- 3123456789
- +393123456789

Comment: Depends. Which regex flavor are you using (programming language/environment/tool)?

Comment: I use gskinner to test my regex.
(http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

I will use C++ librairies in my program (ibm cpp)
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fregcomp.htm

Comment: Boost's regex library has support for conditional replacements (and it's the only one I know that does). So if Boost is an option for you...

Comment: I couldn't compile Boost's regex on IBMi...
Not sure if this is my limited skills on c++, or if the compiler is limited...

Answer (score 0):

Composite the expressions:

```
^(\+393|3|\+39|0)([0-9]{9})$
```

The conditional replacement should be done in code, having a bool member variable specifying whether the number is mobile, according to `$1`.

Comment: And what are you gonna replace it with?